# how can i access variable/ array main project to keyboard extension

Tags: swift4, custom-keyboard

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDXr2.png

array use in keyboard extension not displaying. showing this message on my  console. how to get variable in keyboard extension file.

Comment: Please post your code and the error as text and not as a screenshot

Comment: You should add your code, so others can help you and find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file you want to include and then open the right side pane (it is called the utilities pane.) Find the section called "Target Membership" and click on the checkbox next to your keyboard extension. See the link in my response, it has a screen shot. Then you can access variable into keyboard extension.

[image]